# why the sublime text 3 show the warning information?

Tags: bibtex

Today ,I use thebibliography environment to writ the reference

```
   \documentclass{ctexart}
       \begin{document }
          I use the softwares \cite{           one,two}
       \begin{thebibliography }
           \bibitem{one}
             mathematica 8.0
           \bibitem{two}
            maple8.0
        \end{thebibliography}
  \end{document }
```

However,when I write the \cite{one,},the sublime  text give the warning  information "no bib file found",but when I close the warning window,I write the comma again,the editer appears the list of the bibliography

So I want to know to revise it?